# Get files created before x days, y hours and z minutes in python?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

Hi I have the below program which should give me the list of files created before a given amount of time from the current time

```
def filesOlderThan(path,day,hour,mins):
    file_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for a in files:
            path1 = root + "\\"+ a
            sub_time = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=day,hours=hour,minutes=mins)
            r_time = time.mktime(sub_time.utctimetuple())
            c_time = os.path.getctime(path1)
            if(r_time < c_time):
                file_list.append(path1)
    count = len(file_list)
    return file_list,count

files,count = filesOlderThan("C:\\Arena\\sample",0,0,10)

print count
for a in files:
    print a
```

When I run the program

```
C:\Arena>python getFilesOlderThan.py  
0
```

The program works for values hour values, but does not work with the following input case

1. I set the minutes to 10
2. Create a file inside C:\Arena\Sample
3. Run the program, the program does not give me the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r_time = time.mktime(sub_time.utctimetuple())
```

You're comparing the file's timestamp in localtime withthe current time in UTC.

You should use `timetuple()` instead of `utctimetuple`.

You can make some minor improvements to your function, such as doing calculations using `datetime`s instead of timestamps, using `datetime.now` instead of `today` and using cross-platform `os.join` instead of hard-coded windows separators. It also seems unnecessary to calculate the `len` of the list inside the function - you can do it outside, if it's needed.

```
def filesOlderThan(path,day,hour,mins):
    delta= datetime.timedelta(days=day,hours=hour,minutes=mins)
    now= datetime.datetime.now()
    file_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for a in files:
            path1 = os.path.join(root, a)
            c_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(path1))
            if(now - delta < c_time):
                file_list.append(path1)
    return file_list
```

Finally, if you ever plan on sending these timestamps to another system, remember to convert them to utc (both the file's and the current). You'll probably want to use `pytz` for that.

Comment: shouldn't `if(now - delta > c_time` be `if(now - delta < c_time`

Comment: I was not sure what you wanted, since your code does as you described, but your question stated `the list of files created before a given amount of time from the current time` and the name of the function also seems to indicate so. I'll correct it, then

Answer (score 0):

i create this function but you can modified it

```
import datetime
import time 

def diff(file):
    today = datetime.datetime.today()

    file_mtime = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file))
    t_ob = time.strptime(file_mtime)
    t = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S", t_ob)
    file_d = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")

    minutes = divmod((today-file_d).total_seconds(), 60)

    if (today - file_d).days > 30:
        return f"{round(((today - file_d).days)/30)} months"
    elif (today - file_d).days != 0:
        return f"{(today - file_d).days} days"
    elif minutes[0] > 59:
        return f"{round(minutes[0]/60)} huors"
    elif minutes[0] != 0:
        return f"{round(minutes[0])} minutes"
    else:
        return f"{round(minutes[1])} seconds"

>>>diff("file.txt")
```